# How do I loop through all the files of a folder and save the the files in dataframe format with their name of the file?

Tags: python, dataframe, file, for-loop, bson

I have some Bson files along with its json metadata in a folder. I want to access all the Bson files(only) and store them one by one in a pandas dataframe with the same name as the file(the dataframe name will be the same as its file just without without the .bson extension). How to achieve this?

```
     import bson
     import os
     import pandas as pd
     path_to_bson = 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/home/ubuntu/dump2020'
     bson_files = [pos_bson for pos_bson in os.listdir(path_to_bson) if pos_bson.endswith('.bson')]
     data=[]
     for index,bs in enumerate(bson_files):
         with open(os.path.join(path_to_bson, bs),'rb') as f:
             data=bson.decode_all(f.read())
```

i think if i proceed this way i should get results but im getting an error

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/home/ubuntu/dump2020'

Comment: well, the `os` module has the `listdir` function that lists all the files in a directory. That should get you started and ask a specific question.

Comment: python intepretor doesnt have permission to list files in that directory.